# Masking each word in sentence except first and last letter with a fixed amount of asterisks

Tags: sql, regex, oracle

I want to mask except first and last letter of word in sentence in oracle.

My query is:

```
select regexp_replace('Hello World', '(?<!^.?).(?!.?$)','*') as str2
   from dual;
```

result: Hello World

Expect Result: H***o W***d

Comment: @JvdV `\b` is a zero-width assertion, no need to use it inside lookarounds. Just use `\B`. However, Oracle regex does not support word boundaries, nor lookarounds

Comment: That's even better =) learned a thing there. So it would be: `\B.\B` @WiktorStribiżew?

Comment: @JvdV No, not in Oracle.

Comment: What about `REGEXP_REPLACE('Hello World', '(\w)(\w*(\w))?', '\1***\3')`? Or `REGEXP_REPLACE('Hello World', '(\w)\w*(\w)', '\1***\2')`

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew - [that works](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=7add1ad76245449eac4484f6b40c335b).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use

```
SELECT REGEXP_REPLACE('Hello World', '(\w)\w*(\w)', '\1***\2') as str2 from dual
```

See an [online demo](https://rextester.com/HDJKVH8363)

The regex will only match at least two-letter words, so any one-letter word will remain unaffected.

**Pattern details**

- `(\w)` - Group 1 (later, referred to via `\1`): any word (letter, digit or `_`) char
- `\w*` - any 0+ word chars as many as possible
- `(\w)` - Group 2 (later, referred to via `\2`): any word char.

The `\1***\2` replacement pattern replaces the match with the contents of Group 1, then three asterisks (adjust as you see fit), and then the contents of Group 2.

Comment: @PratikSoni No, it will work with strings containing any amount of words.

Answer (score 0):

If you want words to have the same length and asterisk out each character except for the first and last then you cannot do it with a simple regular expression (as Oracle does not support look-ahead/behind in its regular expressions). But you can do it with a recursive sub-query factoring clause that recursively finds each word and performs the masking on that word and then considers the next word in the string:

```sql
WITH replacements ( value, before, word, pos ) AS (
  SELECT value,
         CASE REGEXP_INSTR( value, '[[:alnum:]]+', 1, 1, 0 )
         WHEN 0
         THEN value
         ELSE SUBSTR(
                value,
                1,
                REGEXP_INSTR( value, '[[:alnum:]]+', 1, 1, 0 ) - 1
              )
         END,
         SUBSTR(
           value,
           REGEXP_INSTR( value, '[[:alnum:]]+', 1, 1, 0 ),
           REGEXP_INSTR( value, '[[:alnum:]]+', 1, 1, 1 )
           - REGEXP_INSTR( value, '[[:alnum:]]+', 1, 1, 0 )
         ),
         REGEXP_INSTR( value, '[[:alnum:]]+', 1, 1, 1 )
  FROM   test_data
UNION ALL
  SELECT value,
         before
         || CASE
            WHEN LENGTH(word) < 3
            THEN word
            ELSE SUBSTR(word,1,1) || LPAD( SUBSTR(word,-1), LENGTH(word)-1, '*' )
            END
         || CASE REGEXP_INSTR( value, '[[:alnum:]]+', pos, 1, 0 )
            WHEN 0
            THEN SUBSTR( value, pos )
            ELSE SUBSTR(
                   value,
                   pos,
                   REGEXP_INSTR( value, '[[:alnum:]]+', pos, 1, 0 ) - pos
                 )
            END,
         SUBSTR(
           value,
           REGEXP_INSTR( value, '[[:alnum:]]+', pos, 1, 0 ),
           REGEXP_INSTR( value, '[[:alnum:]]+', pos, 1, 1 )
           - REGEXP_INSTR( value, '[[:alnum:]]+', pos, 1, 0 )
         ),
         REGEXP_INSTR( value, '[[:alnum:]]+', pos, 1, 1 )
  FROM   replacements
  WHERE  pos > 0
)
SELECT value,
       before AS replaced_value
FROM   replacements
WHERE  pos = 0
```

So for the test data:

```sql
CREATE TABLE test_data( value ) AS
SELECT 'Hello World' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'A short sentence, with a "quote".' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'Some numbers 1000, 2000' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT '==Hello==World==' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'Be in at 10' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT '"!!!!"' FROM DUAL
```

This outputs:

> ```
> VALUE                             | REPLACED_VALUE                   
> :-------------------------------- | :--------------------------------
> "!!!!"                            | "!!!!"                           
> Hello World                       | H***o W***d                      
> ==Hello==World==                  | ==H***o==W***d==                 
> Some numbers 1000, 2000           | S**e n*****s 1**0, 2**0          
> Be in at 10                       | Be in at 10                      
> A short sentence, with a "quote". | A s***t s******e, w**h a "q***e".
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=1ea32122844bdd4e846980cd0e6c17f5)*